# Get Alt value from clicked element and fadein div named element alt value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get div id from clicked img alt value and fade in into that div. I'm here because I'm not jQuery master but trying to learn. Here is my code:

```
$('#div1').bind('click',function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var $divid = $this.attr("alt");
                    $divid.fadeIn(3000);
                });
```

div sample;

```
<div id="div1" alt="div2"></div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: No answer mentions it, so I will: the `alt` attribute is NOT meant to be used this way, and you should not use it on a `div` because it is not valid HTML. Consider `data-` attributes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/M3p4U/

You need to use the alt string to form the id for the JQuery selector.

```
$('#div1').click(function(){
    var divid = $(this).attr("alt");
    $('#'+divid).fadeIn(3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

why all the vars?

```
$("#"+ $(this).attr("alt")).fadeIn(3000);
```

should do

Comment: Vars make code more explicit and easier to read. Combining code like you are doing all inline often makes for much less readable code for other developers who revisit your code or even you revisiting your code months later

Comment: if it is more complex im with you, but I think in this case it is just fine

Comment: I would disagree since you do not easily know that the "alt" attr contains the div's id without those var declarations.

Comment: yea but that isnt a nice nor transparent solution with or without a var

Comment: Sure it could be better but that is not a valid argument to make it worse by removing the vars

Comment: we can argue about the one, but $this instead of $(this) doesnt really win anything but makes the code bigger and thus more unclear.

Comment: I agree in the context of this code $this is useless since it is only used once and does nothing to self document the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a jquery object based on that id.

```
$("#" + $divid).fadeIn(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change third line to `var $divid = $('#'+$this.attr('alt'));`